# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def CannyThreshold(lowThreshold):
            lowThreshold = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Min threshold','canny demo')
            detected_edges = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
            detected_edges=cv2.Canny(detected_edges,lowThreshold,lowThreshold*ratio,apertureSize = kernel_size)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(detected_edges,1,np.pi/180,190)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a= np.cos(theta)
    b= np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    #print 'rho=',rho,' theta=',theta
    cv2.line(frame,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('canny demo',detected_edges)
cv2.imshow('original',frame)

lowThreshold = 23
max_lowThreshold = 50
ratio = 3
kernel_size = 3
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('canny demo')
cv2.createTrackbar('Min threshold','canny demo',lowThreshold,max_lowThreshold, CannyThreshold)

while(1):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  CannyThreshold(lowThreshold)  # initialization
if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

above is my code to detect edges and then draw lines over it in original frame

the error I am getting is given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python_program\hough transform\canny_camera.py", line 37, in <module>
    CannyThreshold(lowThreshold)  # initialization
  File "D:\python_program\hough transform\canny_camera.py", line 11, in CannyThreshold
    for rho,theta in lines[0]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Something is not being assigned properly by the time you're calling the function `CannyThreshold` it's trying to obtain the attribute `__getitem__` from the unassigned variable of `None` type.

Comment: In this example: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/houghlines.py an empty array is passed in as 5th parameter. The docs don't say it's needed, but given the C++ prototype I wouldn't be amazed.

Comment: You should probably also mention the fact that you're using OpenCV.  This fact is missing from your problem statement and you also didn't tag OpenCV in your question (I just did it).  `HoughLines` has the potential of returning `None`, meaning that no lines were detected in your image.  The answer given below essentially describes this fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(detected_edges,1,np.pi/180,190)
```

This lines can be None, then lines[0] results in error

Comment: Yes I sloved the problem using try and except. lines array is returning none type..